# Getting kendo-window parameter

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid, kendo-window

I have a JavaScript method that opens up a kendo-window, this window contains a kendo-grid which has a datasource that I want to get from my controller. In order to get the data to fill this grid I need to pass on an ID. The JavaScript method that opens up this window contains the necessary data, however I do not know how to get this data in my kendo-grid. I need to get my ID to the `(read => read.Action("Read_Action", "ControlerName", new { linenum = ??? })` part where I want to replace the question marks with my ID.

JavaScript:

```
    function showDetails(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        console.log(dataItem.LineNum);
        var wnd = $("#Details").data("kendoWindow");
        wnd.center().open();
    }
```

Kendo-window:

```
@{Html.Kendo().Window().Name("Details")
    .Title("Location Details")
    .Visible(false)
    .Modal(true)
    .Draggable(true)
    .Width(800)
    .Height(600)
    .Content(                                
          Html.Kendo().Grid<TelerikMvcApp1.Models.BinLocationItemModel>()
               .Name("LocItemGrid")
               .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .Model(model => model.Id(m => m.BinLocationItemId))
                    .Read(read => read.Action("Read_Action", "ControlerName", new { linenum = ??? })))
                    .ToHtmlString()).Render();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do this using a controller to open your window content as a partial view.

Set up your controller which will render the partial view and add the id to `ViewBag` to retrieve in kendo window,

```
public ActionResult GetKendoWindow(){
    ViewBag.Id = 123;
    return PartialView("_PartialView"); // Html file name
}
```

Your ***"_PartialView"*** file will now contain the grid only with Id assigned from `ViewBag.Id`

```
Html.Kendo().Grid<TelerikMvcApp1.Models.BinLocationItemModel>()
               .Name("LocItemGrid")
               .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .Model(model => model.Id(m => m.BinLocationItemId))
                    .Read(read => read.Action("Read_Action", "ControlerName", new { linenum = ViewBag.Id }))
```

Your `kendo().window()` method will change to this (without the content as it'll load from the Partial View)

```
@{Html.Kendo().Window().Name("Details")
    .Title("Location Details")
    .Visible(false)
    .Modal(true)
    .Draggable(true)
    .Width(800)
    .Height(600)
    .LoadContentFrom("GetKendoWindow", "Controller")
    .ToHtmlString()).Render();
}
```

If your ID is coming from the parent page (the page you're opening the window from), you will need to pass the ID up to the controller, your `.LoadContentFrom("GetKendoWindow", "Controller")` would then become `.LoadContentFrom("GetKendoWindow?ID=123", "Controller")`.

And your controller declaration would become `public ActionResult GetKendoWindow(int ID)`

Edit: 
As you retrieve the value from JavaScript event, you would preferably want to open your window using JavaScript for simplicity, in your event put the following

```
$("#Details").kendoWindow({
    width: "620px",
    height: "620px",
    title: "Window Title",
    content: {
       url: "GetKendoWindow",
       type: "GET",
       data: {ID : dataItem.ID}
    }
});
```

Remove your `Kendo().Window()` Razor function completely, and leave an empty div with id Details, and open the window using `$("#Details").data("kendoWindow").center().open()`

Complete code for simplicity:

```
<div id="Details"></div>

<script>
// Your event function where you retrieve the dataItem
$("#Details").kendoWindow({
    width: "620px",
    height: "620px",
    title: "Window Title",
    content: {
       url: "GetKendoWindow",
       type: "GET",
       data: {ID : dataItem.ID}
    }
});

$("#Details").data("kendoWindow").center().open()
//End the event function
</script>
```

Then add your controller method from above.

```
public ActionResult GetKendoWindow(int ID){
    ViewBag.Id = ID;
    return PartialView("_PartialView"); // Html file name
}
```

Comment: How would I pass on variable data? for example `("GetKendoWindow?ID=dataItem.ID")` because the ID differs based on the selected item.

Comment: @Alim Like so, ("GetKendoWindow?ID="+dataItem.ID)

Comment: Only dataItem.ID doesn't exist in the kendo-window only in my javascript that opens it.

Comment: This did the trick thank you!, I had one more question since I'm rather new with JS. The part with `$("#Details").kendoWindow({` in you edit that's ajax right?

Comment: @Alim, You're welcome. It isn't ajax at this stage, what you do is define a kendo window for the DOM element with that function and inside the content property you define AJAX method, url etc. The actual Ajax call is made when you call .open() on the window.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `Kendo DataSource additional data` like this:

```
$("#grid").data("kendo-grid").dataSource.read({additional:"data"});
```

This is working on grid demo page: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/remote-data-binding. It adds param to the request.

You could probably set the function returning additional data in dataSource - see the docs: http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-send-values-to-my-action-method-when-binding-the-grid?

**EDIT 1**

You can achieve this simply by setting the grid's additional request data:

```
 $("#grid").data("kendo-grid").dataSource.transport.options.read.data = { additional: "data"};
```

So you open the window with kendo grid. Select the grid with typical `$(...).data("kendoGrid")`. An then set the `dataSource.transport.options.read.data` to your line id.

Comment: The question was how to pass data from parent page to kendo window, not how to refresh the grid with parameter. He wants to fetch the grid with a passed parameter

Comment: I understand - you can achieve that either by starting the grid binding manually or by setting `dataSource.transport.options.read.data` (see editted answer).